# Java error message, tectonicus, libmawt.so

Tags: java, maps, minecraft

After running tectonicus (minecraft map render), i run in to some error, solved a few by upgrading java to 1.6, and installing some libs: x11-libs/libXcursor & x11-libs/libXrandr

But now i got a new error and don't know where to dig next:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
    /root/.tectonicus/native/liblwjgl.so:
    /opt/sun-jdk-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/i386/libjawt.so:
    symbol awt_FreeDrawingSurface, version SUNWprivate_1.1
    not defined in file libmawt.so with link time reference
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1807)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1703)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:770)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1003)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:70)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:82)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:99)
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:130)
        at tectonicus.rasteriser.lwjgl.LwjglRasteriser.<init>(LwjglRasteriser.java:110)
        at tectonicus.rasteriser.RasteriserFactory.createRasteriser(RasteriserFactory.java:24)
        at tectonicus.TileRenderer.<init>(TileRenderer.java:146)
        at tectonicus.TectonicusApp.run(TectonicusApp.java:778)
        at tectonicus.TectonicusApp.main(TectonicusApp.java:1143)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you running tectonicus on a headless machine?

if not check that the DISPLAY environment variable is set correctly
e.g.: DISPLAY=:0 java -jar ...

Comment: yes, my server is "headless", so this map render need a monitor to be used? i started to use pigmap insted, works ok, gets a google map viewer of the world, in one angel, whit posibility to mark places